# Database query for array data type receives error: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

My Tennis Calendar model has a week attribute set as array data type, since tournaments can last two weeks. As an example, the first element is below:

```
2.3.1 :001 > AtpCalendar.first
  AtpCalendar Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "atp_calendars".* FROM "atp_calendars" ORDER BY "atp_calendars"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<AtpCalendar id: 1, name: "Brisbane", category: "ATP 250", week: [1], created_at: "2017-01-25 17:29:36", updated_at: "2017-01-25 17:29:36">
```

If I query Postgresql about the type of the week attribute, I get the expected answer:

```
2.3.1 :001 > AtpCalendar.first.week == [1]
  AtpCalendar Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "atp_calendars".* FROM "atp_calendars" ORDER BY "atp_calendars"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => true
2.3.1 :001 > AtpCalendar.first.week.class
  AtpCalendar Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "atp_calendars".* FROM "atp_calendars" ORDER BY "atp_calendars"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => Array
```

So no issues so far. 
However, if I query Postgres for a particular week value, such as `[1]`, I get an error:

```
2.3.1 :002 > AtpCalendar.where('week = ?', [1])
  AtpCalendar Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "atp_calendars".* FROM "atp_calendars" WHERE (week = 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] = integer
LINE 1: ...LECT "atp_calendars".* FROM "atp_calendars" WHERE (week = 1)
                                                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I also tried a different query, but the result is the same:

```
2.3.1 :001 > AtpCalendar.where("week @> ?", 1)
  AtpCalendar Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "atp_calendars".* FROM "atp_calendars" WHERE (week @> 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] @> integer
LINE 1: ...ECT "atp_calendars".* FROM "atp_calendars" WHERE (week @> 1)
                                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I probably am missing something, but I do not understand what. 
Same error when I use the query `AtpCalendar.find_by(week: [1])`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's actually a string in the db?

```
AtpCalendar.where(week: '[1]')
```

Comment: Close. I found that Postgres uses curly brackets, not square brackets for arrays. So in the end the right query is AtpCalendar.where(week: '{1}')